# julia: how to declare a multi-dimensional array

Tags: multidimensional-array, julia

I'm working with Julia and now I need to use a type named `TimeArray` in the package of `TimeSeries`.

Here is the constructor of `TimeArray`:

```
TimeArray(timestamp::Vector{Date{ISOCalendar}}, values::Array{T,N}, colnames::Vector{ASCIIString})
```

So I do a test here:

```
dts = [Date("2015-01-06"), Date("2015-01-07")]
vls = [[1, 2] [3, 4]]
cnms = ["v1", "v2"]
ta = TimeArray(dts, vls, cnms)
```

It works very well.

Now I have some arrays like this:

```
[1, 2]
[3, 4]
```

It means that I should create the `vls` above with these arrays.

I tried like this:

```
v1 = [1, 2]
v2 = [3, 4]
vls = []
push!(vls, v1)
push!(vls, v2)
```

However I can't create any `TimeArray` with the `vls` here. I got this error:

> column names must match width of array

I also printed the two `vls`.
The first one is:

```
[1 3
 2 4]
```

The second one is:
Any[[1,2],[3,4]]

So I think I must construct the first `vls`, instead of the second one but I don't know how.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The problem is that your `push!()` approach does not produce a 2x2 matrix, but a Vector{Any,2} instead. Thus, `size(vls,2)` is 1, which does not match `length(cnms)`, which is 2.

You might be looking for `hcat(v1,v2)` instead?